# Can one use Docker Trusted Registry with Azure Kubernetes Service?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-container-registry, docker-trusted-registry

Does anyone know if you can use Docker Trusted Registry (DTR) with Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)?  Or is one required to use Azure Container Registry (ACR)?

Thank you!
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has always been possible to use registries beyond ACR with an AKS cluster if access and credentials are provided. You can read more details from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-aks?view=azure-devops&tabs=java)